# App Script para Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-hoja-de-cálculo

tengo un Script en una hoja de calculo de Google, el script envia registros a FireBase y esta configurado para que lo haga cuando detecta un cambio. El problema es que cuando se realiza un cambio en una fila, envia nuemavamente todas las filas y no solo la fila editada.

Quisiera saber si existe la posibilidad de que pueda verificar si existe un registro similar en FireBase y que ya no lo envie, y en caso de no existir o haber sido modificado entonces lo actualice.

````
  // 1. Iniciamos las variables
  const firestore = getFirestore();
  // pedir datos al domcuento
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "eov";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  // pedir la ultima fila y columna para definir el rango
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  // definir la primera fila para leer
  var dataSR = 3;
  // deifnir el rango de datos
  var sheetRange = sheet.getRange(3,1,lastRow-dataSR+1,lastCol);

  //get data
  var sheetData = sheetRange.getValues();
  var sourceLen = sheetData.length;

   var formatedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "MM/dd/yyyy-00:00:00")

  //obtener en largo para establacer un loop
  for (var i=0;i<sourceLen;i++){
    var data = {};

    data.flt = sheetData[i][0];
    data.eov = sheetData[i][1];
    data.telef = sheetData[i][2];
    data.date = new Date(formatedDate);
      Logger.log(data);
    firestore.createDocument("despachadores",data)
  }
} ```
````

Comment: Quizá si me muestras cómo se ven los datos pueda ayudarte. de momento se me ocurre que podrías usar una expresión regular para separar cada línea, algo cómo /.*\n$/ y solo enviar esa línea, pero sin ver exactamente lo que quieres lograr no puedo estar seguro.

Comment: Si la Hoja está ligada a un formulario, puedes escuchar los eventos del formulario, o los eventos de la lista con change o edit, recuperar solamente el elemento que ha cambiado y mandarlo a Firebase para su comprobación. Ten en cuenta que Firebase computa cada lectura / escritura, por lo que escribir un código que mande datos indiscrinadamente podría ser problemático en muchos contextos.

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de usar getLastRow y column, que podrian llegar a causar problemas si por ejemplo si ingresa algun dato fuera de lugar, o se agregan varias celdas al mismo tiempo, puedes usar el objeto que el activador onEdit regresa, como menciona la [documentacion aqui](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers?hl=es-419#onedite) regresa un objeto e, este objeto e, se define [mas en esta documentacion](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) que dentro, tiene dentro otro objeto de tipo rango, que [esta aca](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) no lo veo mencionado en la documentacion, pero al probar en Apps Script que regresa, esta regresando columnStart y end y tambien rowStart y end que se pueden usar para tener el rango especifico de celdas que se cambiaron, y despues usar el getValues para saber los valores de ese rango en especifico.

Para el getValues, como en el ejemplo de [su documentacion](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) muestras, primero agarra un getRange con 4 valores los primeros dos la celda donde comienza, y los otros dos las filas y columnas apartir de ahi, asi hace una matriz y despues getValues regresa esa matriz como un objeto